# How is it possible to use a very reduced version of WordPress?

Tags: publish

My dream would be to code a website just with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and then connect parts with a very simple CMS.

For example, I would have a text area, and just write in HTML something like that:

```
<p class="text-area wordpress-editable"><p>
```

And then my CMS is constructed this way:

- I login the admin panel
- There I see only the pages and subpages that I can rank
- I can click one
- See the `.wordpress-editable` fields, for example `Text Area`
- Can put there my text
- Save
- The changes are published

It would be so simple to have such a system. And I think it would be interesting to use a minified WordPress version for it. Did ever someone work one something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question .. Flat-file by definition doesn't use a classical database but the filesystem. WordPress does heavy use of its classical database, so I would imagine you'd have to go through extreme hardships to combine them. And for what? If you want WP for its extendibility, you should use core WP as that gets lost if you do too much manual under the hood. If you like WP for Gutenberg, you can use that standalone. If you don't like WP, use another tool/framework from the start.

Comment: strictly speaking what you've described would not be a flat file CMS, a flat file CMS would store its contents in flat HTML files. It sounds instead like you want to build a static website without learning any PHP or WordPress and just use HTML classes to sprinkle javascript for editable areas and database content. btw I would suggest looking into block based themes, a block theme is almost entirely HTML with some blocks acting as placeholders for post titles and content.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I was wrong with my imagination of a flat-file system, so I corrected my post. @TomJNowell You're right, thats what I am looking for. Is it easy to program such a block based theme? Or is it better to just take an existing theme and connect the components with the HTML documents?

Comment: And I actually like how this works: http://www.coast-cms.de/ – But unfortunately, it seems not to be possible to add subpages and update the navigation with it.

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to avoid doing work and learning things, and in the process doing a lot of work :) The default theme that comes with WordPress is a block based theme, and WP Tavern regularly covers new releases that show up in the main WP Admin dashboard, it would be easier for you to look at a block theme than to discuss it at this point. Why describe a sunset when you can just look at it? Keep in mind the comments are for clarifying the question, not for writing answers

Comment: @TomJNowell I think that's not the truth. I think my life is not so easy, I studied in a completely different area, got a disability, and learned HTML, CSS, and JavaScript just because I was curious. I just feel that most content management systems are unnecessarily complicated. I hope that such systems will soon be replaced by for example simpler node-based systems. And yet, I am willing to learn PHP and WordPress. Still, I noticed that the community seems to be pretty strict, most tutorials seem to be very theoretical, and not playful and I am not sure if I want to waste my energy with it.

Comment: And thank you for the WordPress block theme recommendation. I'll look at it.